# Resolving type of exception declared in Catch expression

Tags: c#, roslyn, analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I have been working on some **Roslyn code analyzer**. My goal is to analyze exceptions and `Catch` blocks.

I got to a situation when I am able to analyze nodes and get `NamedType` of every `Exception` possibly thrown by the node. At the same time I am able to enumerate all `Catch` blocks related to such a node.

I need to **resolve whether given `NamedType` is equal to `Catch` expression declaration** or its base class.

Illustrative code:

```
var typeName = "System.ArgumentNullException";
NamedType exceptionType = _compilatorStartContext.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName(typeName);
// exceptionType = NamedType System.IO.IOException

var tryStatement = arg as TryStatementSyntax;
CatchDeclarationSyntax @catch = tryStatement.Catches.First();
var declaration = @catch.Declaration;
// declaration = CatchDeclarationSyntax CatchDeclaration (Exception)
// TODO: decide whether declaration can be instantiated from exceptionType
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the semantic model for that.

After you get hold of it you can do this:

```
// var declaredType = analysisContext.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(@catch.Declaration).Type;
// ^^ only works on catch(FooException x), doesn't work on catch (FooException) 
var declaredType = analysisContext.SemanticModel.GetTypeInfo(@catch.Declaration.Type);
var implements = false;
for (var i = declaredType.Type; i != null; i = i.BaseType)
{
    if (i == exceptionType)
    {
        implements = true;
        break;
    }
}
// implements holds the result
```

Comment: I forgot to say I tried this approach. The issue here is that `analysisContext.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(@catch.Declaration)` returns `null`.

Comment: @JiříTravěnec ah, I see, the issue is that `GetDeclaredSymbol` doesn't work with declarations without a variable identifier, e.g. `catch (InvalidOperationException) { ... }`, see updated answer

Comment: This gives me `ArgumentException` with detail stating "Syntax node is not within syntax tree".

Comment: @JiříTravěnec then you don't have the right semantic model for the tryStatement. Can you update your question to show exactly how you get the tryStatement and the semantic model? Any way, if you're not rewriting any syntax trees, you should be able to get the right semantic model with `_compilatorStartContext.Compilation.GetSemanticModel(@catch.SyntaxTree).`

Comment: I have combined everything you mentioned and it works. I will try to post final solution some time later. Thx.